# Can anyone tell me how to add gzip in php site

Tags: gzip

What code should I use in my site:www.metroquickpick.com and where to add I try in .htaccses so many code it said not working. I have no idea how to add and what code for gzip my host is yahoo they said they can't help me

Comment: how did you try to enable the same via .htaccess? what server they use?